# Likelihood of my friend being able to guess skittle taste

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, variance, expected-value

I'm preparing for a data science interview, and here's a question I encountered during my preparation:

> Your friend claims he can tell the five colors of skittles apart by
> taste alone. The probability of a skittle being any particular color
> is 1/5. You give your friend 3 skittles and he gets 2 correct. Should
> you believe him? What if you give him 100 and he gets 40 correct?

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, I should believe them in both instances. Here's my reasoning:

Let $X_i$ be an indicator random variable equalling $1$ if my friend is correct on the $i^{\text{th}}$ guess so that $E(X_i) = 1/5$ and $\text{Var}(X_i) = 4/25$.

The expected number of successful outcomes are 3/5 and 20, and the variance on three guesses is $12/25$, so guessing two correctly is more than two SD above the mean, and the variance on $100$ guesses is $16$, so they are just over one standard deviation above the mean.

I'm really not sure if my reasoning is correct, and I'd appreciate any sort of insight.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_tasting_tea

Comment: I could *guess* the colors of the three skittles and have a $13/125$ chance of being correct on two or more of them.  Using a Z score (that is, expressing the result in terms of SDs above the mean) is not a good procedure with such a small dataset.

Comment: Okay, that clears things up. So I guess it would be appropriate to use Z-scores for the $n = 100$ case but not the $n = 3$ case. This means that I should still be skeptical after $n = 3$, but should I still be skeptical after $n = 100$? I'm not sure if I should be comparing my friend to getting everything right or getting above $20$ right?

Comment: The claim is that he can "guess the colors" (indeed it specified "he can tell the five colors"), not that he can "guess somewhat better than mere chance". I feel we're perhaps testing a much weaker claim than he seems to be making. In an interview that had this question my first step would be to say "I'd ask my friend to clarify his claim; is he claiming he can guess all the colors (as it seems to be saying) or is he merely claiming he can do a bit better than chance - or indeed, is he claiming something else?"

Comment: @Glen_b From my understanding, the answer that I accepted tests whether he can "guess somewhat better than a mere chance," right? If we wanted to instead test the claim that he can guess all the colors, then how would I compute the $p$-value?

Comment: Yes, it tests "better than chance". How you'd compute the p-value for the "gets all 5 colors right" claim depends on how you decided to test it (what specific test statistic). If the claim is that he gets them all, then anything less than 100% accuracy could be grounds to reject (So I'd suggest Test statistic: *count the errors*. Rejection rule: *reject if >0*). The p-value would be either 1 (no errors) or 0 (any errors). If you wanted to test some lesser claim (like saying "guesses right half the time" or "guesses 4 out of 5 right") then you'd use a different statistic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the first case with 2 out of 3 correct: Under the null
hypothesis that your friend is purely guessing, the number
correct is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=3, p=1/5).$ A test of the null hypothesis against the the alternative that $p > 1/5$ rejects for
large values of $X.$ So the P-value for outcome $X = 2$ is
$P(X \ge 2) = 0.104 > 0.05 = 5\%$ and you would not reject at the $5\%$ level. The evidence does not require you to believe
your friend can identify color by taste. [Computation below in R, but summing two terms using the binomial PDF is not difficult.
*Note:* If your friend got all three right, the probability of that just by guessing is $(1/5)^3 = 0.008$ and you *should* be convinced.]

```
sum(dbinom(2:3, 3, 1/5))
[1] 0.104
```

However, if your friend gets 40 out of 100 correct, then
the null distribution is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=100, p=1/5)$
and the P-value is $P(X \ge 40) \approx 0.$ So without
ability to judge color by taste, this outcome would be very rare.
You should believe your friend has some ability.

```
sum(dbinom(40:100, 40, 1/5))
[1] 1.099512e-28
```

By normal approximation to $\mathsf{Binom}(n=100, p=1/5),$
you have $\mu = E(X) = np = 20,\;$ $\sigma^2 =Var(X) = 16,\;$ $\sigma = SD(X) = 4.$ Then

$$P(X \ge 40) = P(X>39.5)\\ = P\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} > \frac{39.5-20}{4} = 4.875\right)\\ \approx P(Z > 4.875) \approx 0, $$
where $Z$ has a standard normal distribution.

```
1 - pnorm(4.875)
[1] 5.440423e-07
```

In the figure below, the P-value is the (very small) sum of heights of bars to the right of the vertical dotted line. The red curve shows the density function of the approximating normal distribution.

[image]